# What can I do to make Eclipse PyDev editor more reactive?

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I use Eclipse with [PyDev](http://pydev.org/) to develop Python code, and I wouldn't want to miss all its useful IDE features. One thing is a little annoying: The latency between when I type and when the source code changes is a little to high. (Not as snappy as, for example, Sublime Text 2.)

Is this due to overhead of some editor features which can be disabled? Can I do something to tune my editor settings for speed and responsiveness?

File size might be a factor, but it's hard to tell. It is not fast enough with small files.

System Info:

MacBookAir3,2

Mac OS X 10.6.8

java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-10M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

PyDev Version 2.5.0

Comment: Does this happen on any file or only big files? Can you give more information on your machine/setup? It'd also be nice having a screenshot (so that I know what you may be using when that happens). If you're able to give that info, I can take a look at profiling for your specific use-case to check if something can be improved in the PyDev side.

Comment: I added setup info. What should the screenshot be of?

Comment: A screenshot of the IDE (mostly to see views open).

Comment: See this screenshot: http://postimage.org/image/704lwjbed/full/

Comment: In your screenshot you have a big file... you said previously that "File size might be a factor, but it's hard to tell. It is not fast enough with small files.", so, I'd like to know a bit more here: do you 'feel' a difference on large vs small files? (i.e.: I know faster is better, but are changes not acceptable only on large files or on small files too?)

Comment: I cannot tell if file size really matters, if there is a difference it is very small. What I do often is indenting blocks of code, and the delay depends on the number of lines in the block. Overall, the speed is still acceptable in all cases, it's just a small delay that might cause typos if you type fast.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using OpenJDK, switching to Oracle JDK also improves responsiveness.

Comment: How can I check which one is installed?

Comment: Mac OS X 10.6. I use the Java distribution that comes with OS X.

Comment: It seems that OS X uses Oracle Java by default. You could also try to update Java to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you are looking for, but anyway:

- Stop and deactivate unnessesary services.
- Increase RAM
- Configure or deactivate resident software, like antivirus and such. If you can deactivate for a  short period of time just to find out if it  changes something, without compromising security.
- Switch your CPU, depending on your mainboard specs, sometimes mainboards come wiht a low cost CPU and an upgade is possible.
- Get a bigger and faster machine

Comment: Indeed, not what I am looking for. But to give some hardware info: I have a Macbook Air with 4 GB of RAM and a 2 x 1.8 GHz CPU. CPU load goes up quite a bit when I edit source code in PyDev, but the overall system load is not the problem.